# Xamarin.Forms - 'Foundation' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I've created a new 'Blank Xaml App (Xamarin.Forms Shared)' app in Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2.

Immediately after creating the project, I was greeted with 217 errors.
Restarting Visual Studio removed most of those, but 35 still remain.

The first two errors are about `Foundation` and `UIKit` not being found. I believe these two might also cause the rest of the errors.

Does anyone have some ideas as to how to solve these?

```
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Foundation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'UIKit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: `Foundation` and `UIKit` are apart of `Xamarin.iOS.dll`. Make sure you have a reference to `Xamarin.iOS.dll` in your `Xamarin.iOS` project.

Comment: @JonDouglas `Xamarin.iOS.dll` is indeed not referenced. I tried to right click on `References` and then `Add reference...`, but I don't see any Xamarin references there. How do I add this? I'm completely new to Xamarin.

Comment: Make sure that you have installed Xamarin.iOS on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing the reference to `Xamarin.iOS`, try re-adding it manually:

Under the Xamarin.iOS project, right click `References > Add Reference...`

In the references dialog, on the left hand side, click on `Assemblies`, then `Framework`. Search for `Xamarin.iOS` and select it to add the reference.

If the `Xamarin.iOS` assembly isn't listed, take a look under this path:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0`

If the assembly is missing from that directory, try repairing the Xamarin installation - Windows `Programs and Features > Xamarin > Repair`.

Comment: There is no `Xamarin.iOS.dll` in that folder. There is a `Xamarin.iOS.dll.mdb`.

Comment: @Daan In that case you might need to re-install Xamarin for Visual Studio, making sure you select to install the Xamarin.iOS SDK. I have had problems before where doing a System Restore has caused assemblies to go missing, or it could be your previous install didn't finish correctly, or something else.

Comment: I thought the same thing and did this already. I go this same error after doing that, also when I did it in a virtual machine.
Maybe it's better to contact Xamarin?

Comment: @Daan Have you checked your antivirus to see if anything is being blocked/quarantined? Only other suggestion is uninstalling, maybe manually remove the aforementioned directory, and re-install.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as possible. Thank you for the suggestion!