# How to check Device iPhone has set up App Google Maps in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem is open maps with Google Maps:

My device iPhone has set up App Google Maps, but my app when press button links to maps app to open maps. Device opens Safari, don't open Google Maps.

I try this way: [Xamarin Forms - Maps - Is possible to call Google Maps from a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781475/xamarin-forms-maps-is-possible-to-call-google-maps-from-a-button)

But At line code:

```
var canOpenNative = UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("comgooglemaps-x-callback://"));
```

I can't use library: `**using *Foundation***;

(Build app will can't use library.)

And I try this way: [Xamarin.Forms - 'Foundation' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219349/xamarin-forms-foundation-could-not-be-found)

But when build app I can't build with library **Foundation**.

So, Has a other ways, How to check Device iPhone sets up App Google Maps in Xamarin.Forms?

Thanks!

Comment: You can call native code via a Forms' dependency service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Comment: Has set-up Google Maps as in installed on device or set up as in set as default mapping app?

Comment: @Adriani6 I want check on device (iPhone) has set up Google Maps. If device has not App Google Maps, device will open maps to Safari or other app maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use Foundation assembly from your Shared Code then You can only access that from your iOS platform specific project.

You can call platform specific code from your shared code using the dependency services. Follow these steps to create dependency service to check whether IPhone has Google Maps installed:

**Step 1 :** Create an Interface in your Shared Code

```
public interface IMapService
{
     bool HasGoogleMapAvailable();
}
```

**Step 2 :** Now In your platform specific project; For now its your iOS project. Create an Service which will implement the Interface you created:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MapService))]
namespace WorkingWithMaps.iOS
{
    public class MapService:IMapService
    {
        public MapService()
        {
        }

        public bool HasGoogleMapAvailable()
        {
            var result=UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString("comgooglemaps-x-callback://"));
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3 :** In your shared code you can use that Dependency service :

```
IMapService mapService = DependencyService.Get<IMapService>();
var isInstalled = mapService.HasGoogleMapAvailable();

Console.WriteLine("Google Map is installed :" + isInstalled);
```

**Step 4 :** To actually open the Map; You can use Device.OpenUri which will show popup to users to select any from all installed map application on the device:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Google+Inc,+8th+Avenue,+New+York,+NY&daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York&directionsmode=transit");
Device.OpenUri(uri);
```